# Count columns that have both 0 and 1

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a table that contains 0, 1 and -9.

```
-9  -9  0   1   1
-9  1   0   0   0
0   -9  0   1   -9
-9  -9  1   0   -9
-9  -9  0   0   0
```

I want to know how many columns have both 0 and 1.
In the example, the answer is 3.

I was thinking about combining `awk` and `print` to print "true" in case the column contains both 0 and 1 (and print false otherwise).

I'd have then `| grep true | wc -l` to count the number of column.

Does it sound like a good solution? Or how can I do that with `awk`?

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you want to count values in columns vertically? What if the 1st line in your current input is `-9  0 -9   1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        if      ($i == 1) ++one[i]
        else if ($i == 0) ++zero[i]
}
END { 
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        c += (one[i]>0 && zero[i]>0)
    print c
}' file
```

This counts the ones and zeros in two separate arrays, `one` and `zero`. These have one entry per column in the input file.

At the end, the `c` variable will be the sum of the number of columns that has both at least one `1` and one `0`.  The code assumes that the number of columns in the last line of input is the same as in the other lines of the input data.

The output of this with the given example data is `3`.

Comment: Thank you this is working very well and that is a very smart solution!

Answer (score 2):

ruby is nice for working with arrays of arrays:

```
ruby -e '
    rows = File.readlines( ARGV.shift ).map {|line| line.split}
    columns = rows.transpose
    puts columns.count {|column| column.include?("0") and column.include?("1")}
' file
```

or, without variables

```
ruby -e 'puts readlines
                .map {|line| line.split}
                .transpose
                .count {|column| column.include?("0") and column.include?("1")}
' file
```

Comment: According to habit we both mixed up rows and columns.

Comment: @hauke, handled

Comment: can also use `readlines` alone instead of `File.readlines(ARGV.shift)` as a short-cut...

Answer (score 1):

try with (this ugly)

```
awk '{if ( NF>maxi) maxi =NF ; 
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ( $i == 0 ) zero[i]=1 ; 
               if ($i ==1 ) one[i]=1 ;}}
     END { for (i=1;i<=maxi;i++) if ( zero[i]+one[i]==2) print i ;}' file
```

this basically setup a flag for `0` and `1` for each column. sum of both must be 2.

Comment: Thans for your answer. It doesn't provide the column number though.

Answer (score 1):

With BSD `rs`:

```
<file rs -T | grep -w 0 | grep -wc 1
```

Where:

- `rs -T` transposes the matrix
- `grep -w 0` selects the rows (formerly columns) that contain 0 as a single `w`ord
- `grep -wc 1` counts the number of remaining rows (initially columns) that contain `1` as a single word

Note however that *words* for `grep -w` are sequences of alnums or underscores, so while `1` wouldn't be found in `10`, it would be found if `-1` as `-` is neither alnum or underscore.

If `-1` may occur in the input, you may want to change it to:

```
<file rs -T | sed 's/.*/ & /' | grep ' 0 ' | grep -c ' 1 '
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would be great but I don't find the command rs.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i] = (NR > 1? a[i] : "") $i; }
     END{ 
         for (i in a) if (a[i] ~ /(0.*1|1.*0)/) c++;
         print c 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
3
```

Comment: I tried with this file and it works but with other text files it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

With **`datamash`** + **`awk`** supposing your fields are separated with a single space:

```
$ datamash -t' ' transpose <infile | awk '/0/ && /1/{++C} END{print C}'
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This might work but data mash probably need to be installed first...